# Indexing into a PowerShell value collection

Tags: powershell, collections

Given:

```
$settings = @{"Env1" = "VarValue1"; "Env2" = "VarValue2" }
Write-Output "Count: $($settings.Values.Count)"
Write-Output "Value 0: '$($settings.Values[0])'"
Write-Output "Value 1: '$($settings.Values[1])'"
```

I get the output:

```
Count: 2
Value 0 : 'VarValue2 VarValue1'
Value 1 : ''
```

Why does the first element have both values and the second have none? How do I get the values as a collection I can index?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use nested hashtables for that? I can't help but feel that an array would be more useful somewhere in there rather than a hashtable.

Comment: Actually, nested hashes are irrelevant. I've update the question to remove them.

Comment: `$settings.Values` do not have indexer. You can not index it. In PowerShell v3+ `[0]` for not indexable objects simply return you original object: `[Object]::ReferenceEquals($settings.Values, $settings.Values[0])`. If you enable strict mode (`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`), then `$settings.Values[1]` will show you `CannotIndex` error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution is to convert the Values ICollection to an array of strings.

With:

```
$values = $settings.Values -as [string[]]
```

The output becomes as originally expected:

```
Count: 2
Value 0 : 'VarValue2'
Value 1 : 'VarValue1'
```

I cannot help but feel that this should be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly index a hashtable like that. Gotta do this

```
($settings.GetEnumerator() | select -expand value)[0]
```

From `help about_hash_tables`

> Hash table tables are not arrays, so you cannot use an integer as
>   an
>        index into the hash table, but you can use a key name to index into the
>        hash table. If the key is a string value, enclose the key name in quotation
>        marks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I'm not indexing the hashtable. I'm indexing the Values property on the hashtable.

Comment: You can't though, at least not directly. I showed you how. It is part of the hashtable so it is built differently and is not an indexable array like you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your $settings object, you can simply use » ($settings).Values

Example:

```
($settings).Values | % { '• ' + $_ }
```

Returns:

```
• VarValue2
• VarValue1
```